# Add a class retrieved from a sibling field to responsive image

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I have a **Profile** paragraph type that has the following fields:

- Profile Image [Responsive Image Field format]
- Profile Headline [Plain Text]
- Profile Description [Plain Text]
- Rounded Profile Image [Boolean]

What I'm trying to do is that when the `field_rounded_profile_image` boolean is selected, that it will add the `rounded-circle` class to the image attributes of the `field_profile_image` field.

Currently, this is what the code for the image looks like when it is printed:

```
<div data-quickedit-field-id="paragraph/196/field_profile_image/en/default" class="field field--name-field-profile-image field--type-image field--label-hidden field__item">
  <picture>
    <source srcset="/sites/default/files/styles/profile_large/public/paragraphs/image/profile/image1.jpg?h=74e1741d&amp;itok=WLlku9ED 1x, /sites/default/files/styles/profile_large/public/paragraphs/image/profile/image1.jpg?h=74e1741d&amp;itok=WLlku9ED 2x" media="all and (min-width: 992px)" type="image/jpeg">
    <source srcset="/sites/default/files/styles/profile_small/public/paragraphs/image/profile/image1.jpg?h=74e1741d&amp;itok=p2VQAa0P 1x, /sites/default/files/styles/profile_small/public/paragraphs/image/profile/image1.jpg?h=74e1741d&amp;itok=p2VQAa0P 2x" media="all and (min-width: 768px)" type="image/jpeg">

    <img src="/sites/default/files/styles/profile_small/public/paragraphs/image/profile/image1.jpg?h=74e1741d&amp;itok=p2VQAa0P" alt="Image" typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-fluid">

  </picture>
</div>
```

I'm trying to write a preprocess hook to do this but this part of my Drupal game is lacking so I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

I've tried something along the lines of the following to no avail:

```
// Note that me adding the __profile_card below does work due to another hook I have running to allow me to specify which paragraph type to target
function MYTHEME_preprocess_paragraph__profile_card(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['content']['field_rounded_profile_image'][0]['#markup'] == "On") {
    $variables['content']['field_profile_image']['attributes']['class'][] = "rounded-circle";
  }
}
```

Any help on this would be great and I can provide any follow-up details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd recommend is to simply preprocess the paragraph, get the "round image" Boolean, and use it to add a class to the paragraph. This should be just enough to style the responsive image accordingly.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_paragraph__PARAGRAPH_TYPE.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_paragraph__profile_card(&$variables) {

  // Get paragraph.
  $paragraph = $variables['paragraph'];

  if (!$paragraph->get('field_rounded_profile_image')->isEmpty()) {

    // Get Boolean.
    $rounded = $paragraph-> field_rounded_profile_image->first()->getValue();

    if ($rounded['value'] == '1') {
      $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'rounded-image';
    }
  }
}
```

And then via CSS (Sass) you'd do:

```
.paragraph-profile-card {
  &.rounded-image {
    .field-profile-image {
      // rounded image styles
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It definitely works. The reason I wanted to just add the class to the image was due to the fact that I already have that modifier class available globally and figured it'd be one less style to add. But again, this works too, so thanks again!